# Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for port 587

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer

When I call `ContactMailer.contact_us(@user).deliver_later` I get:

> Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for
>   "282.71.137.66" port 587):app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:17:in
>   `block in create' app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:15:in`create

or sometimes

> Net::OpenTimeout execution expired error

My appliction.rb file:

```
config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
config.time_zone = 'Asia/Kolkata'
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => 'smtpauth.net4india.com',
  :port => 587,
  :domain => 'pop.net4india.com',
  :user_name => "username@oakridgebs.com",
  :password => "password",
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

I tried to rescue this error but in this case I am not getting email delivered. Do you know any other solution?

Comment: What is an output of `host smtpauth.net4india.com` ?

Comment: I am also getting same error. Did you get the solution to this problem?